# Fetching data from javascript using Ajax into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from javascript into PHP file, using Ajax.
Here is what I tried

**.js file**

```
 function showHint() 
 {
     let lolData = $('#lol').val();
     $.ajax({
          url:'http://localhost/data.php',
          type:'post',
          data:{d:lolData},
          success(data){
              //console.log(data);
             // alert(data);
             $('#lol1').empty().val(data);
          }
     })
  }; 

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showHint);  
  });
```

**PHP file**

```
  <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "uppercase";
  $i = "1";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $data = $_POST['d'];
  echo $data;
  $sql = "SELECT phish_url FROM phishtank WHERE idd = 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // echo $row["phish_url"];
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }

  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

When I try to echo the value of `$data` in my PHP file, I get the error

> Undefined index: d

I have no idea why I m getting this error.

Comment: Did you check your console for js errors? and try to echo var_dump($_POST);die; and show that here

Comment: run this code and check your console: `let lolData = $('#lol').val();
     console.log(lolData);` is it `undefined`?

Comment: My lolData variable has the value I checked it.

Comment: `success(data){` should be `success: function(data){`

Comment: @shaswat-kumar it should be `success: function(data)` and you wrote the wrong code

Comment: why am I getting error (Undefined index: d)cwhen I try to echo it in my php file?

Comment: I think the php file name or its path is wrong ?